# How to center images vertically in the UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a UITabBar without titles and I need to center tabs images vertically. How I can to this? I know that I have to subclass the UITabBar, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only reason you want to subclass UITabBar is to have an image only tab bar you might be better off with one of the custom tab bar controllers from [cocoacontrols](http://cocoacontrols.com/)

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I need